# Elasticsearch MapperParsingException[failed to parse, document is empty] during indexing

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elastica

I am using elasticsearch 1.2.2 with php wrapper elastica

while indexing some documents i encountered the following exception

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Elastica\Exception\Bulk\ResponseException' with message 'Error in one or more bulk request actions:

index: /en_search/en_msg/936 caused MapperParsingException[failed to parse, document is empty]
' in /root/search/vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Bulk.php:395
Stack trace:
#0 /root/search/vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Bulk.php(345): Elastica\Bulk->_processResponse(Object(Elastica\Response))
#1 /root/search/vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Client.php(284): Elastica\Bulk->send()
#2 /root/search/vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Index.php(147): Elastica\Client->addDocuments(Array)
#3 /root/search/vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Type.php(187): Elastica\Index->addDocuments(Array)
#4 /root/search/setData.php(36): Elastica\Type->addDocuments(Array)
#5 {main}
  thrown in /root/search/vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Bulk.php on line 395
```

Now the the document that it fails to parse is this one which is obviously not empty.

```
array(
    [id] => 936
    [uid] => 3222
    [msid] => 211
    [login] => user1222
    [msg] => Wouldn’t you love a cup right now?
)
```

document mapping was something like this

```
$mapping->setProperties(array(
    'id'  => array('type' => 'integer', 'include_in_all' => true),
    'uid' => array('type' => 'integer', 'include_in_all' => true),
    'msid' => array('type' => 'integer', 'include_in_all' => true),
    'login' => array('type' => 'string', 'include_in_all' => TRUE),
    'msg'  => array('type' => 'string', 'include_in_all' => true), 

));
```

doing indexing in bulk mode as suggested here 
**[elatica.io:  Bulk indexing](http://elastica.io/getting-started/storing-and-indexing-documents.html#section-bulk)**

i  am pretty sure it's caused by `’` character. Not sure if it requires escaping . in case it does how do i escape such characters?

Comment: Can you share the code in which you are doing bulk request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved . it was an encoding problem.  my data was coming from mysql server , i had to set the correct charset option during pdo object initialization.

Comment: And what charset was that?

Answer (score 0):

It is an encoding problem due to special chars, I recomend to escape the text you're trying to index with

```
$text = html_entity_decode(htmlentities($text, ENT_IGNORE, "UTF-8"));
```